# how to convert a varchar field value into an integer field

Tags: postgresql

for example in a table one field is `character varying` so how to convert that `character varying` to an `Integer` type, what exactly is I need to get the *return* value in `Integer` *datatype*

Database : [postgresql-9.2](/questions/tagged/postgresql-9.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to make *Functions* to do the job i.e

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chartoint(charparam character varying)
    RETURNS integer AS
    $BODY$
    SELECT CASE WHEN trim($1) ~ '[0-9]+' THEN CAST(trim($1) AS integer) ELSE NULL END;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
```

Comment: this answer is more convenient

Comment: [Never use `SIMILAR TO`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql/10696#10696). I suggest `trim($1) ~ '\d+'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
SELECT NULLIF(your_value, '')::int
```

or extend that like thats

```
SELECT CAST(coalesce(column_name, '0') AS integer) as Value
from table_name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT mycolumn::integer FROM mytable WHERE something 

SELECT CASE WHEN mycolumn = NULL THEN NULL ELSE mycolumn :: Integer END
FROM mytable WHERE something
```

Comment: `NULL` can be converted to `integer` without problem. Empty strings or non-digits would raise an exception.

Comment: `WHEN mycolumn = NULL` will not work you need: `WHEN mycolumn is NULL` - but that isn't necessary as Erwin already said. `when trim(mycolumn) = ''` would be better